# accessing a parent of a parent relationship laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am building an application in laravel in which each channel has some sections and you can post threads in the sections. I would like to access the channel from the thread.
The hierarchy so far is this
-channel
--section
---threads

here are the three model classes

channel

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Channel extends Model
{
    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
    public function isSubscribed($id){
        return $this->users()->find($id);
    }
    public function sections(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Section');
    }
}
```

section

```
{
    public function channel(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Channel');
    }

    public function threads(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Thread');
    }
}
```

thread

```
{
    protected $fillable=['title','body','solved'];

    public function solutions(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Solution');
    }
    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\ThreadComment');
    }
    public function section(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Section');
    }
    public function arguments(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Argument');
    }
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function reports(){
        return $this->morphTo('App\Report','reportable');
    }
}
```

what I would like to do is to have a `channel()` method in thread class that makes me access the channel without having to do `$thread->section->channel` each time

Comment: There isn't a `belongsToThrough` method in Laravel (inverse of `hasManyThrough`), so you can use an accessor (as stated below), in conjunction with `Thread::with('section.channel') ...` to perform eager loading, or use an external package that add that relationship, like https://github.com/staudenmeir/belongs-to-through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a problem using a package for this, use https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep. You can have any levels of relationships.

Read the usage section of the package for details.

Comment: this package worked just fine. Using an accessor worked too but this keeps the overall code clean

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to, use an accesor.

```php
public function getChannelAttribute()
{
    return $this->section->channel;
}
```

Comment: already tried but getting this ```LogicException with message 'App/Thread::channel must return a relationship instance.'```

Comment: @gloria00 What code produces that error? Are you calling `$thread->channel` or `$thread->getChannelAttribute()`? (Cause one of those will work while the other will not). Please check the documentation for them here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Comment: You get that error because you named the function `channel()` instead of `getChannelAttribute()`.